# How to use an object created on another method in Java?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jlabel

I'm new to Swing, and I want to know how to use an object that was instantiated on one method, in another method. I need to add that `label` to the `frame` object, but I don't want to do it from the `createFrame` method. So, what can I do?

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FrameCreation.createFrame(600, 600, "Test");
        FrameCreation.createLabel("Whatever");
    }
}

public class FrameCreation 
{
    public static JFrame createFrame(int width, int height, String name) 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return frame;
    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(String text) 
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're returning the newly created frame... but completely ignoring it in the `main` method. Hint: `JFrame frame = FrameCreation.createFrame(600, 600, "Test");` and go from there...

Comment: Don't use all static methods. I suggest you start by reading the Swing tutorial for Swing basics. Maybe start with the `LabelDemo` found in the section on [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for a better way to structure your code.

Comment: Do I understand right that you no longer need help? Please consider adding your own answer (you'll be able to accept it in 48 hours if nobody provides a better answer for you). That way it saves people from spending time trying to find a solution you don't need. Please see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @ThiagoFerronatto Don't vandalize your own questions. They need to remain as questions for future readers. If you don't want that, delete it altogether, but it's not what this community is for.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you want to add a JLabel to a JFrame, you have to create a JPanel. The order is the following one:

JFrame -> JPanel - > JLabel

So you can write (in the main):

```
JFrame frame = FrameCreation.createFrame(600, 600, "Test");
JLabel label = FrameCreation.createLabel("Whatever");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);
frame.add(panel);
```

Comment: There is no reason to add the label to a panel first. The content pane of the frame is a JPanel. You can just add the label to the frame and it will be added to the content pane for you.

Comment: You need to add your JLabel to a visible container, otherwise it cannot show up on the screen.

Comment: @SimoneC. Components added to a container after `setVisible()` won't show up until the container is validated.

Comment: @SimoneC., you add your components to the frame (there is no need for an additional panel) and then you use `frame.pack()` and then `frame.setVisible()` to show the frame and all of its components.

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution, here we go:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FrameCreation.createFrame(600, 600, "Test").add(FrameCreation.createLabel("Whatever"));
    }
}
```